# How to Choose Light mode while using Mobile Camera?

Tags: image-quality, android, smartphone

Which mode is best fit to take pictures at dusk using a mobile camera,will auto mode work fine or something else.

For your information:
I use a moto-e and Nexus 4 as my camera.
and i use the default camera app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a substitute for trying it and seeing for yourself.  "Dusk" can be anywhere from near golden hour conditions when Auto will do great to almost dark where a night time mode will do better.  The exact settings and conditions can vary greatly from phone to phone and day to day.

If the image is coming out dark or noisy, try switching to a night time mode that is more focused on reducing noise and increasing the use of limited light that is available.  I don't know about the exact modes available on your camera, but each mode should have strengths in terms of image quality.  Look at your image, determine what problems, if any, are present and then change to the mode that best addresses those issues.